# singularities and residues

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Consider the function $$f(z)=\frac{z^3}{1-\cosh(z)}$$. Find its singularities and compute residues.

I know the denominator vanishes for $z_k=2k\pi i$, $k$ integer. I first consider $k=0$, so the function is analytic in $0<|z|<2\pi$, and i can write in this punctured disc the following Laurent expansion:

starting from $$\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ i get $$\cosh(z)=\cos(iz)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$Hence $$1-\cosh(z)=-\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^4}{4!}\ldots$$
thus i can write $$\frac{1}{1-\cosh(z)}=\frac{1}{-\frac{z^2}{2!}-\ldots}=-\frac{2}{z^2(1-h)}=-\frac{2}{z^2}(1+h+h^2\ldots)$$ where $h=-\frac{2z^2}{4!}-\frac{2z^4}{6!}-\ldots$.
So we have $\frac{1}{1-\cosh(z)}=-\frac{2}{z^2}+\frac{4}{4!}+$ higther terms.
Finally, we get $\frac{z^3}{1-\cosh(z)}=-2z+\frac{4z^3}{4!}$+ higther terms, from which i desume that $z_0=0$ is a removable singularity for f.

But now i don't know how to deal with $z_k$ with $k\neq 0$. I imagine those to be all poles of order 2 for $f$, but how to prove?

A last question: is it correct to say: the poles $z_k$ accumulates to $\infty$, hence $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity, thus i cannot compute $Res(f;\infty)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the same procedure.  The Taylor series for cosine near $z = 2k\pi$ is the same as its series at $z = 0$ because of periodicity.  So

$$
\cos z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(z-2k\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!},
$$

hence

$$
\begin{align*}
\cosh z &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(iz-2k\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z+i2k\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
\end{align*}
$$

Then rewrite the numerator of $f(z)$ as

$$
\begin{align*}
z^3 &= (z+i2k\pi-i2k\pi)^3 \\
&= (z+i2k\pi)^3 - i6k\pi(z+i2k\pi)^2 - 12 k^2\pi^2 (z + i2k\pi) + i2k^3\pi^3.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I guess this gives you the Laurent series for $f$ near $z = -i2k\pi$.  If you'd like, you can just replace $k$ by $-k$ to get the series near $z = i2k\pi$.

Comment: thanks, using your suggestion i computed $res(f,z_k)=24k^2\pi^2$, which i hope to be correct

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni yup, you got it :)